# Directly using typed arrays for attributes in three.js

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to directly use TypedArrays in three.js for custom attributes? I'm downloading a binary model format from a server, and the data is directly stored into a Float32Array. Since this is the format required by gl.bufferdata, it seems wasteful to create THREE.Vector3 objects, which only get stored back into a new Float32Array inside WebGLRenderer.js.

As a possibly unrelated issue/bug, I've profiled this binary model loading in Chrome and noticed that 60% of the time is spent in the garbage collector. This is seriously bogging down the model loading, since there are over 100k vertices in this model. This only started happening since v49 I believe. Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BufferGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/core/BufferGeometry.js). Sadly we don't have many examples of how to use that one yet. Only [CTMLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ctm/CTMLoader.js#L218) is using it at this point. Maybe it can serve as good reference for you?

Comment: Is it possible to use custom attributes which are typed arrays as well?

Comment: After carefully inspecting WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect, it appears that the answer is **no** for custom attributes. I suppose I could modify it to support that. I may submit a pull request in the future...